# Assign list of a class type to object type list

Tags: c#

I have a list as below:

```
IList<Employee> emp = new List<Employee>
            {
                new Employee() {Id=1, Name = "A", Age = 20,  Address = "X"},
                new Employee() {Id=2, Name = "B", Age = 21,  Address = "Y"},
                new Employee() {Id=3, Name = "C", Age = 22,  Address = "Z"},

            };
```

and another list:`IList<Object> emp2=new List<Object>();`
If I want to assign emp to emp2 like:`emp2=emp;` how can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
foreach (var employee in emp)
{
    emp2.Add(employee);
}
```

Comment: how can I order emp2 by any property of emp?

Comment: use `OrderBy` (suppose you want to sort base on `Id`): `emp2 = emp2.OrderBy(e => (e as A).Id).ToList()`;

Comment: You could call `OrderBy()` on emp rather than emp2, and thereby avoid the `e as A` bit.  Then insert a call to `Cast<object>()` before `ToList()` and you're done in one line of code.  See my answer for an example.

Answer (score 1):

I would do this:

```
List<Employee> emp = //insert initialization code here
IList<object> emp2 = emp.OrderBy(e => e.WhicheverPropertyYouWantToSortBy).Cast<object>().ToList();
```